# Table using div does not apply width or text ellipses

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a simple table which should truncate text with ellipses if it overflows the width.

However it seems the width is not being applied. Please see this in action:

[Table width jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46p2Lokj/9/)

Also copying the code here:

**EDIT: added header and a div wrapper around all rows, which is not working with fixed layout**

```
<div>
<div class="table">
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
        header
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        123
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        456
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        789
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        110
    </div>        
</div>
<div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
        This is a very long line of text that should be trimmed
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        123
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        456
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        789
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        110
    </div>        
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
        This is a very long line of text that should be trimmed
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        123
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        456
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        789
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        110
    </div>        
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table {
 display:table;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%
}

.row {
display: table-row
}

.cell {
display: table-cell;
width: 20%;
white-space: nowrap;
padding: 5px;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: It seems to not be working with `display: table-cell`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add `table-layout:fixed;` and `width:100%;` to your table CSS:

```
.table {
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/46p2Lokj/8/)**

```css
.table {
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">This is a very long line of text that should be trimmed</div>
        <div class="cell">123</div>
        <div class="cell">456</div>
        <div class="cell">789</div>
        <div class="cell">110</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">This is a very long line of text that should be trimmed</div>
        <div class="cell">123</div>
        <div class="cell">456</div>
        <div class="cell">789</div>
        <div class="cell">110</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it does work in a simple div structure, but as I just posted the edit, I have a header div section as well as a div outside all rows. This fails to work with the fixed layout.

Comment: Because you broke the structure with the nested divs. Now you have a table > div > row > cell. Is this what you're after http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8e0jn5sp/?

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you! That's it. So its the div under the table that needs to be laid out like a table! Thank  God!

Answer (score 0):

You could set it to a specific px width:

```
.cell { max-width: 20px; } //Hard-coded width
```

Comment: I wish i could. I am building a dynamic dashboard with a lot of user options and which should work in all sorts of resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you can do without the `display:table-cell`

I tried this and it seemed to work

```
.cell {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 20% !important;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;

}
```

Comment: This is surely a step forward. I can see the ellipses and the header cell widths are correctly aligning but the actual row widths are not spanning the entire width. In fact in my real code the last cell wraps down below the row. There seems to be something about the wrapper div around the rows. I am forced to have that div to house the knockout foreach binding.  http://jsfiddle.net/46p2Lokj/15/

Comment: that's because of the padding on each cell (which is why I removed it) - if you add 5 columns x 20% you get the full width of the page (100%) but if you add padding on top of that, it will exceed the width of the page and flow down.  You can either reduce the percentage (width) of each cell or reduce the padding or a combination of both.  I suppose you could also make the table have a width greater than 100% but I am not sure that is desirable.

Comment: I also removed the `layout:fixed` see if this works: http://jsfiddle.net/46p2Lokj/16/